# Why is GoLand issuing a warning on SCSS code?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, goland

I have the following (correct) code in a Vue component, edited from GoLand

```
<style lang="scss">

.q-dark div,
.body--dark div {
  &.calendars {
    color: #fefefe;
    background-color: black;
  }

  &.forecast {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

</style>
```

GoLand complains about this code:

[image]

The same code edited in WebStorm does not show any warnings.

Is there something I should configure or add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure you have **SASS** plugin installed, it doesn't come bundled with Goland: in **Preferences | Plugins, Marketplace** search for `SASS`, choose to install it